# Raising to powers in C++ vs. Python

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading, operators

Coming from Python, I've noticed things in C++ tend to be a little more complicated.  A good example would be raising numbers to a power.  In Python's math library, all that is needed is:

```
a = a**b
```

**However, in C++ I've found explanations in online documentation such as.....**

```
//float
pow( float base, float exp );
//double      
pow( double base, double exp );
//long double 
pow( long double base, long double exp );
//float
pow( float base, int iexp );
//double      
pow( double base, int iexp );
//long double 
pow( long double base, int iexp );
//promoted    
pow( Arithmetic1 base, Arithmetic2 exp );
```

Obviously the creators of C++ must have had great reasons for making it this way, but as a new programmer, those reasons elude me.  Does this give greater flexibility over the answer?  What benefits have I been given here in C++ in terms of powers?

Comment: The major reason is that C++ is statically typed, while Python isn't.

Comment: It's not that simple. You show Python from usage perspective and C++ from declaration perspective. C++ code from usage perspective would be `a = pow(a,b)`, hardly more verbose than Python counterpart. OTOH, from declarations point of view, you have at least `long.__pow__()`, `float.__pow__()` in Python.

Comment: @el.pescado, now that you mentioned it, where would I be able to find python internal implementations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers in python have no limit. Some consequences that arise out of this is that programs tend to be slower since python is not statically typed, and has more overhead since it does not know if a number is within a certain range. In short, the main reason for using overloading functions in that way is for speed purposes, and it's easier to reason about what's happening under the hood. Python provides a lot of conveniences, but sometimes become very difficult to reason about.

Secondly, most languages have a math.pow function (Java also for example), and while it's a bit verbose, I think it's still very easy to understand. Note that when you call pow() in C++, **the compiler will figure out which of the pow(some data type, some data type) should be called and there is no need to worry over the multiple definitions.**

Comment: "You have the same pow" - rubbish.  There are several completely different functions with different implementations and different signatures - but the same name.  As a matter of convention (well, in the case of `pow` it's a matter of the standard) these different functions are all doing the same mathematical operation, and compiler *does* figure out which function to call - but it is not the "same" pow.

Comment: Yes, the compiler figures this out through function overloading...perhaps I should rephrase this. I was trying to emphasize how on the end user side the same pow function is called. There is no need for a powForFloats(), powForInts() etc.

Comment: You keep saying "the same pow function", but my point is that it absolutely is **NOT** the same pow function.  It's the same name - but a different function.

Comment: For the end user, the Math.pow function is called. Internally, different functions are chosen by the compiler. The part I wanted to emphasize that might need to phrased more frankly, is that while there are multiple implementations of power from C++, you do not need to worry about which one is called, since this is automatically figured out.

Comment: Right.  That's *much* better.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey Untitled, your edited post makes a lot of sense.  Thank you for the clarification.  It looks like the creators of C++ did a wonderful job of making pow as simple as possible considering it's statically typed.

Comment: There's also something called type promotion in C++, that explains what happens if you pass in data types that are not covered by an existing parameter data type. For example if a function takes in double parameters, you're able to call it with an int due to upcasting. At the same time, this stuff isn't as important for regular usage, but is useful when one wants to explain what's going on under the hood.

Answer (score 8):

The multiple declarations you found are a result of C++ having **static types** vs. Python's **dynamic types**. In Python when you call a function on a value it can determine at runtime if you are calling it on an integer, float, or some more complex object and take the appropriate actions. In C++ you can't call the same function with different types so you must declare a different version of the function for all the types you wish to support. However unlike in C, you can have functions with the same name that differ only in their parameter signature, (as Untitled123 points out, this is called **function overloading**). This actually makes your life easier since you can just call `pow(a,b)` without having to worry about which special function to call for the types you want (e.g. `pow_float_int(a,b)` or `pow_float_float(a,b)`), the compiler will call the correct version for you based upon the types of the arguments.

Comment: @Untitled123 Yes. That was my point. I'm not sure what you're saying, function overloading still requires multiple functions to be defined. I guess I could have been clearer when I said 'you can't call the same function with different types.'

Comment: Could you delete the  This actually makes your life easier since you can just call pow(a,b) without having to worry about which special function to call for the types you want (e.g. pow_float_int(a,b) or pow_float_float(a,b) part, this is very misleading

Comment: detail: This answer demonstrates how C++ differs from python in this respect from an implementation standpoint, but even heavily overloaded functions can be expressed in the form of operators. For example consider std::ostream that overloads << operator to take in various types of input, but this detail is hidden from the end programmer.

Comment: The original version of that line had a point about how pow_float_int is necessary to be called, and I didn't catch that he had changed the first part of the sentence originally.

Comment: Hey Turn, thank you for the comprehensive answer.  It helped a lot.  It was really hard trying to decide which answer was better between yours and Untitled's.

Comment: Untitled123, I'm happy to edit further for clarity (I've only added text so far) but can you tell me why you think it is misleading?

Comment: @ForeverStudent Yes, you're right. I avoided commenting on that bit because I personally find the operator overloading feature of C++ to be abhorrent. I understand not everyone agrees with me!

Answer (score 3):

The benefits of having multiple function signatures is in compile-time optimization vs. run-time decision.

In Python, `**` operation looks at its arguments at run time and decides what algorithm to apply. The integer exponent vs. rational exponent vs. arbitrary floating point unlimited precision exponent vs. complex exponent vs. whatever else. This decision takes time.

In C++, as compiler sees `pow(x, y)`, it knows the types of `x` and `y` at the compilation time, so it can pick the best matching `pow()`. That, in turn, allows the compiler to avoid any kind of runtime decision making. Depending  on how headers are written and/or the presence of whole program optimization, the compiler can even inline the call and avoid any kind of runtime expense apart from actually computing the power.

This usually does not matter much. However, if your `pow()` call is in a tight loop with millions of iterations, it can be significant.

Comment: If there was an operator in C++ for power it too could resolve to calls at compile time.  Obviously a**b can't be done because *b is a deref etc.  But I think a^b could be possible as long as one of a, b was a floating point (otherwise ^ is xor between ints).  I do wish that C++ had a nicer way to raise floats to small integer powers at the least.

Comment: The operator is just syntactical sugar. The important thing is how C++ allows this kind of optimization not just for language constructs or standard library but to arbitrary allocation code. Oh, and you can define operator ^ for float and int, although that's not a good idea.

Comment: Actually, in gcc I get invalid operand types for float, int.  Why not a good idea?  I admit that it's just sugar but it can be nice translating numeric codes from Fortran, etc.

Comment: I think my idea is not just a library addition but a language change.  I think the powers did not want anyone to be able to railroad operators between fundamental types.  I think conforming compilers will all prevent a^b unless both are integral.  And you shouldn't be able to override the operator in any case.  I still think a^b would be a nice pinch of sugar though.

Comment: Look up operator overloading in C++. And it's a bad ideas because the original meaning of the operator would get in the way.

Answer (score 1):

as you know in c++ we use function for Power instead of operators ( like python )

you can use pow as like as above examples. There are several modes for use of this function and every time you send different variables to it, system decides which mode to choose . **pow( float base, float exp );** and **pow( double base, double exp );**  are not the same and each are a separate function

Now when you go to the Python there are exactly same state . ** Operator is like the C++ functions that have different modes . Just like the definition of [the operators in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

I hope you understand my tip